# 100% width with transition in css

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar on the left of a page:

```
#list {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #262626;
    color: #494949;
}
```

And a menubar with 3 optionbuttons on the bottom of the page. So the buttons have to be equally big and shoudl be next to the navigation bar. So 300px to left. It shoudl look somethign like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qnrm.jpg

I tried with float: left; but it didnt work either. 
I dont really know how to get these 3 bars in the full width and equally divided over this area. It might be  a bit unclear what I want to achive. But please ask what isn't clear and I will try to explain it to you! Thanks :)

Comment: Give your html code. So that we can see, whats wrong.

Comment: can you use jquery? i can give you a solution with that

Comment: Problem occurring because of position:fixed. Try use position:relative or position: absolute instead of it.

Comment: Search for `display: table`, `table-row` or `table-cell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Review this Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/9RYhR/22/**

I don't use Jquery only a `width` of `33.3%` for each item an `padding-left` for his container equal to the width of your sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Using calc you can get the width.

http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/vne79/

HTML:

```
<div id="list"> The Menu </div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
       <p> ... </p>
    </div>
</div>

<nav>
    <a href="" class="one">Link 1</a>
    <a href="" class="two">Link 2</a>
    <a href="" class="three">Link 3</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

```
#list {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #262626;
    color: #f00;
}

#container {
    margin-left: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc( 100% - 300px - 20px ); /* 100% - width of nav - padding */
    height: 100%;
}

nav {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;

    margin-left: 300px;
    width: calc( 100% - 300px );
    bottom: 0;
}

nav a {

    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    width: calc( 100% / 3 ); /* could use 33.33333% as well */
    float: left;
}

.one { background: #5ff; }
.two { background: #f5f; }
.three { background: #ff5; }
```